# Button won't go to a url when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, url, button

Having problems with my js buttons. Right now, they work perfectly, but I am trying to turn my "Order Online" button into a link that opens up a new window to a Menufy menu page. However, I can't seem to figure it out. Right now the buttons are set up as tabs, basically.

```
<section class="menu_options"> 
      <button class="menu_btn" onclick="displayMenu('dine-in');">Dine in</button> 
      <button class="menu_btn" onclick="displayMenu('take-away');">Take Away</button>
      <button class="menu_btn" onclick="displayMenu('lunch');">Lunch</button> 
      <button class="menu_btn" onclick="displayMenu('online');">Order Online</button> 
</section>

displayMenu = function(menu){
  $(".menu_inner").find(".menu-active").toggleClass("menu-active").slideToggle();
  $(".menu_inner").find("#"+menu).toggleClass("menu-active").slideToggle();
}
```

Comment: Open a window inside your `displayMenu` function?

Comment: Are you using the debug console in your browser? Are there any errors? Did you step through the code?

Answer (score 0):

To change your button into a link, you can try it as follows

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="displayMenu('online');">Order Online</a>
```

> The void operator evaluates the given expression and then returns
>   undefined.
>
> The void operator is often used merely to obtain the undefined
>   primitive value, usually using “void(0)” (which is equivalent to “void
>   0”). In these cases, the global variable undefined can be used instead
>   (assuming it has not been assigned to a non-default value).

The reason why `void(0)` is used is because, if it isnt specified, the default behaviour of `<a>`, that is redirecting to the href specified will be nullified and the `onclick` specified will be called

Answer (score 0):

Using this code "window.location.href='url'" works to take you to a new url within your window, i.e.:

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='url.com'">Click me</button>
```

Whereas, if you want to open the link into a new window, use this:

```
<button class="menu_btn" onclick="window.open('url.com', '_blank')">Lunch</button>
```